# Are both Maimonides and Nachmanides called Rambam? If so why?

Tags: rambam, ramban

- Maimonides’s full name was [Moses ben Maimon](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/moses-maimonides-rambam); in Hebrew, he is known by the acronym of Rabbi Moses ben Maimon, Rambam.
- [Moshe ben Nachman](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/moshe-ben-nachman-nachmanides-ramban) (Nachmanides or the Ramban) was the foremost halakhist of his age.

I have seen both Maimonides and Nachmanides called Ramban, apparently since both were known as Rabbi Moses/Moshe.  Is there are rule of thumb as to which sage is referred to when a quote is attributed to "Ramban" without further clarification?

---

**Note**: I have just found the answer to the question when looking for tags... I simply hadn't noticed that "Ramba**n**" (ending in "n" is ben-Nachman) and "Ramba**m**" (ending in "m") is ben-Maimon. I will go ahead and ask the question in case others are confused as I have been.

Comment: "Are both Maimonides and Nachmanides called Rambam?" - nope!

Comment: Then please answer your own question.

Comment: To avoid this confusion, Jerusalem has a "Ramba**n** Street", and a "Ben-Maimon Street."

Comment: I don't have an objection to this question being closed since I learned what I needed to learn, but I wonder how it does not fit within the help center's scope, which includes - history of Judaism and
- language used in Judaism.

Answer (score 1):

*I was asked by @Shalom to answer my own question. When I went to tag the question I discovered one tag for Rambam and another for Ramban. I had simply failed to distinguish between the two. So here's the answer:*

It's easy for someone not well educated the rabbinical tradition to get confused about this. But no, they are not both called Rambam. This name is an acronym given to [Maimonides](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Maimonides), or Rabbi Moshe ben Maimon, shortened to the acronym Ra-M-Ba-M. Ergo: Rambam. (רמב"ם)

[Nachmanides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides), on the other hand, is call Ramban, with an "n" at the end, a short version of Rabbi Moses ben Nachman using the acronym Ra-M-Ba-N. (רמב״ן)

Comment: And to avoid confusion, convention is to stress the syllables differently. Maimonides is RAM-bam; Nachmanides is Ram-BAN.